# Significato di "intrallazzo" in questo contesto

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *La Storia*, di Elsa Morante, ho letto:

> Mussolini e Hitler, a loro modo, erano due sognatori; ma qui si manifesta la loro diversità nativa. La visione onirica del «duce» italiano (rispondente a una sua voglia materiale di vita) era un festival da commedia, dove fra labari e trionfi lui, vassalluccio d’**intrallazzo**, recitava la parte di certi antichi vassalli beatificati (i cesari, gli augusti...) sopra una folla vivente umiliata al rango di fantoccio.

Potreste spiegarmi il senso del termine "intrallazzo" in questo brano? Nei dizionari che ho consultato ho visto che significa "attività disonesta" o "imbroglio", ma non riesco a capire cosa vuol dire "vassalluccio d'intrallazzo".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Da Treccani per [vassallo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/vassallo/):

> 2. estens. e fig. a. Individuo o ente strettamente subordinato e dipendente rispetto a un altro: *un v., i v. di un potente uomo
>      politico; non sono mica il suo v., io!*

e per [intrallazzo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/intrallazzo):

> Per estens., intrigo, compromesso disonesto, attività equivoca per
>   accaparrarsi favori e influenza, soprattutto in campo politico:
>   *un’amministrazione corrotta, basata sugli i.; candidati che ricorrono
>   all’i. per accaparrarsi voti;* più genericam., ogni attività o
>   comportamento che cerchi di raggiungere un fine non per le vie più
>   regolari, ma attraverso compromessi, taciti accordi, connivenze,
>   sfruttando la propria o altrui influenza, e sim.: *chissà quanti i. per
>   ottenere quel posto!*

L’espressione vassalluccio d’intrallazzo, riferita a Mussolini, voleva significare che egli era subalterno a Hitler in quanto non aveva una statura politica paragonabile.

L’uso del vezzeggiativo per vassallo serve proprio a sminuirne la figura, con intento chiaramente derisorio e dispregiativo.

Intrallazzo si riferisce al fatto che per mantenere il potere Il Duce utilizzava qualsiasi metodo, lecito o illecito, e a quei tempi la corruzione era dilagante così come il malaffare.

Comment: Vezzeggiativo, più che diminutivo, e, sono d'accordo, usato con intento chiaramente derisorio e dispregiativo. Un modo per dire che il Duce era un piccolo intrigante.